# C++: rvalue references used in ternary operator seem to break existing code

Tags: c++, c++11, ternary-operator, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

I'm currently porting one of my projects, which has been developed for years using Borland C++-Builder 5 and 6, to the most current Embarcadero C++-Builder XE 3 Update 2. XE 3 supports some of the new C++11-things like rvalue references which is of course completely new to me, due to the former used very old compilers. I needed only very few modifications to get my project compilable, but during runtime I'm facing one problem which seems to be a result of the new rvalue references and move semantics.

I have a class with a field of type std::wstring storing a path which is only read from one method using this field in a ternary operator like the following:

```
std::wstring retVal = someCondition ? this->classField : Util::doSomething(someArg);
```

someCondition is just a call to std::wstring.empty() and Util::doSomething returns std::wstring as a value, no reference or else involved, just copied data.

With XE 3, after the first time someCondition evaluated to true, retVal gets properly filled with the content of classField, but afterwards classField's content is empty. Using the debugger I could follow execution to an optimized assignment operator whith rvalue references:

```
 #if _HAS_RVALUE_REFERENCES
[...]
    _Myt& operator=(_Myt&& _Right)
        {   // assign by moving _Right
        return (assign(_STD forward<_Myt>(_Right)));
        }

    _Myt& assign(_Myt&& _Right)
        {   // assign by moving _Right
[...]
```

What I've read about rvalue references would perfectly explain my problem, I even found two comments explaining why my classField is treated as an rvalue.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8535301/2055163

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6957421

I can fix the line above with one additional manual copy of classField:

```
std::wstring retVal = someCondition ? std::wstring(this->classField) : Util::doSomething(someArg);
```

But this doesn't solve the problem that I need to review each and every usage of a ternary operator (where lvalues and rvalues are mixed) in each project I want to port without any help from the compiler, because it's a runtime problem that may or may not occur.

What I don't understand is if there's something wrong or bad practice with my usage of the ternary operator? Are there better solutions to detect those cases? Why should I manually copy some objects just to trick optimizations? Is this really intended behavior and no problems in most of your codebase out there? How do you deal with such problems?

I'm a bit confused on how to progress right now and would really appreciate any suggestions and/or explanations. Thanks!

---

I tested the following two cases which worked:

http://ideone.com/mWxxK3

The first example looks similar to my case, expect that no class instances are used to store the global string. dummy2 is properly filled and dummy keeps its content.

```
std::wstring retVal = someCondition ? this->classField : doSomethingResult;
```

When I change my line above to remove the rvalue by saving the result of Util:... to a std::wstring before using the ternary operator, everything works as expected. retVal has its content and this->classField keeps its, too.

What's the conclusion now? :-/

Comment: Maybe a compiler bug.  What's the return type of `Util::doSomething`: does it return by value or return a reference?

Comment: I returns by value and depending on my quoted links the behavior I see is what I would expect, I just don't understand why it's a "good thing" to do. My two expressions used with the ternary operator are a lvalue and a rvalue, resulting in the whole expression is used as an rvalue, therefore applying move semantics.

Comment: What does your compiler do with this program?  http://ideone.com/YwLjgi

Comment: Please note that in @aschepler's example, the compiler elided move-construction of `test`.

Comment: The result is a prvalue `string` copy-initialized from the second or third operand (5.16p6); copy-initialization from an lvalue will not invoke move semantics.

Comment: @ecatmur: The result of the expression is not an lvalue.  p6 says "If the operands have
class type, the result is a prvalue temporary of the result type".

Comment: Yes, if there is no elision, you would see inside `main` "Copy ctor / Move ctor / Destructor / Destructor".  But there MUST be at least one copy ctor call.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I don't see any xvalue subexpressions anywhere.

Comment: @aschepler: I realized that and edited.  It is a temporary though, and eligible to be moved.

Comment: @BenVoigt the lvalue I was referring to is the subexpression `this->classField`, which Thorsten's compiler is apparently moving from.

Comment: @ecatmur: That subexpression is supposed to be used to initialize a temporary prvalue.  The move construction I mentioned is of `test`, not the temporary.

Comment: @aschepler Your test program issues one copy ctor call. The order is as following: Default ctor, Begin main(), Copy ctor, Destructor. This is proper behavior in opposite to what I currently have, isn't it?

Comment: @aschepler I modified your test program to something similar with my problematic line: http://ideone.com/mWxxK3 In this case, the global dummy variable keep it's contents and the move ctor(?) "basic_string(_Myt&& _Right)" gets called. Looks like there was an implicit copy cto which content got moved afterwards to dummy2.

Comment: So it sounds like you haven't reproduced a problem with simpler code.  Maybe some other code was actually stepping on `this->classField` unexpectedly?  Try to reduce the full program and/or expand the ideone examples until you find the answer or have a http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a compiler bug.  The relevant section of the Standard is 5.16p6:

> [If] The second and third operands have the same type; the result is of that type. If the operands have class type, the result is a prvalue temporary of the result type, which is copy-initialized from either the second operand or the third operand depending on the value of the first operand.

---

If `Util::doSomething(someArg)` returned `std::string&&` instead of a value, we'd need section 5.16p3:

> Otherwise, if the second and third operand have different types and either has (possibly cv-qualified) class type, or if both are glvalues of the same value category and the same type except for cv-qualification, an attempt is made to convert each of those operands to the type of the other. The process for determining whether an operand expression `E1` of type `T1` can be converted to match an operand expression `E2` of type `T2` is deﬁned as follows:
>
> - If `E2` is an lvalue: `E1` can be converted to match `E2` if `E1` can be implicitly converted to the type "lvalue reference to `T2`", subject to the constraint that in the conversion the reference must bind directly to an lvalue.
> - If `E2` is an xvalue: `E1` can be converted to match `E2` if `E1` can be implicitly converted to the type "rvalue reference to `T2`", subject to the constraint that the reference must bind directly.
> - If `E2` is an rvalue or if neither of the conversions above can be done and at least one of the operands has (possibly cv-qualified) class type:
>
>   - if `E1` and `E2` have class type, and the underlying class types are the same or one is a base class of the other: `E1` can be converted to match `E2` if the class of `T2` is the same type as, or a base class of, the class of `T1`, and the cv-qualification of `T2` is the same cv-qualification as, or a greater cv-qualification than, the cv-qualification of `T1`. If the conversion is applied, `E1` is changed to a prvalue of type `T2` by copy-initializing a temporary of type `T2` from `E1` and using that temporary as the converted operand.
>   - Otherwise (i.e., if `E1` or `E2` has a nonclass type, or if they both have class types but the underlying classes are not either the same or one a base class of the other): `E1` can be converted to match `E2` if `E1` can be implicitly converted to the type that expression `E2` would have if `E2` were converted to a prvalue (or the type it has, if `E2` is a prvalue).

The fourth bullet applies, so a copy should be made automatically, with no changes needed to your source code.

---

In both cases, the temporary copy can then be moved safely when constructing `retval`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to apply; the second and third operands have the same type (`string`) and different value categories (lvalue and prvalue respectively), so the implementation should fall through to 5.16p5, giving a prvalue of type `string`.

Comment: @catmur: Anyway, it seems like both rules yield the same result: a temporary object distinct from `this->classField`.

Comment: The first sentence of the paragraph doesn't hold (the operands have the same types but different value categories) so the implementation doesn't get to the bullets.  Bullet 4 is meant for `string a; const string b; p ? a : b;` or `struct C {}; struct D: C {}; C c; D d; p ? c : d;`.

Comment: Also, 5.16p3 doesn't allow conversions in both directions, so it's not much use where the types are the same.

Comment: I agree with @ecatmur: Paragraphs 5 and 6 apply here, not paragraph 3.

Comment: Exactly, since the two operands have the same type, any 5.16p3 conversion would work in both directions making the program ill-formed.  That's why 5.16p3 doesn't apply to the same-type case.

Comment: ... but with the same result: the conditional expression is a prvalue copy-initialized from the second or third argument.

Comment: @ecatmur: I was thinking in terms of one being `std::string&` and the other `std::string&&`.  But you're right, those references don't actually exist (yet), the differentiation is in value category.  (The references are created in order to call the constructor and initialize the prvalue temporary).

Comment: @catmur: I've gone ahead and fixed it.  (I hadn't seen Thorsten's comment with the actual return type at the time I looked up the section in the Standard; I didn't know which of these cases applied)

Comment: You were absolutely right, it's a compiler bug. Thank you all for your help! https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=527267&tstart=0#527267